# How to automatically display <div class> from if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a javascript condition for my html page. And got stuck in this problem. The problem is, i try to make div class="content" automatically appear when the times is >=13 o'clock and the seconds is <=10. Its working smoothly, but i must refresh the entire page to make the div class="content" appears. Is there a way to make the div automatically appears when the if condition meet the requirements? Please Help

There is my code

```js
var timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var greeting;
var popup;
var d = new Date();

if (seconds < 10 && hour >=13) {
  greeting = "Past 10 Seconds";
  document.querySelector(".content").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.querySelector(".content").style.display = "block";
} else if (seconds < 30) {
  greeting = "After 10 & Before 30 Seconds";

} else {
  greeting ="Past 30 Seconds";
  document.querySelector(".content").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  document.querySelector(".content").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = d.getSeconds();

function myTimer() {
  var s = new Date();
  document.getElementById("tiktok").innerHTML = s.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="seconds"></p>
<p id="tiktok"></p>

<div class="content">
  <h1>FLASH SALE!!</h1>
  <p>PRODUK KECANTIKAN</p>
  <button id="myBtn" 
  onclick="window.location.href='https://tokopedia.com';">Check 
  Out</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't inside your interval callback. So why should it execute peridically? Makes sense?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone yes its make senses now. Thank you very much ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving everything inside the `myTimer()` function should do it.

```
var timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var s = new Date();
    document.getElementById("tiktok").innerHTML = s.toLocaleTimeString();

    var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var greeting;
    var popup;
    var d = new Date();

    if (seconds < 10 && hour >=13) {
        greeting = "Past 10 Seconds";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.display = "block";
    } else if (seconds < 30) {
        greeting = "After 10 & Before 30 Seconds";

    } else {
        greeting ="Past 30 Seconds";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.display = "block";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = d.getSeconds();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the logic which updates the `status` element only runs once, and so to have it the element update every second you need to move it into `myTimer()`:

```js
const timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    const d = new Date();
    const seconds = d.getSeconds();
    const hour = d.getHours();
    let greeting;
    let popup;

    if (seconds < 10 && hour >= 13) {
        greeting = "Past 10 Seconds";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.display = "block";
    } else if (seconds < 30) {
        greeting = "After 10 & Before 30 Seconds";
    } else {
        greeting = "Past 30 Seconds";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        document.querySelector(".content").style.display = "block";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    document.getElementById("tiktok").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="seconds"></p>
<p id="tiktok"></p>

<div class="content">
    <h1>FLASH SALE!!</h1>
    <p>PRODUK KECANTIKAN</p>
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="window.location.href='https://tokopedia.com';">
        Check Out
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a blank div in html like and set display property as block using java script when your condition is met

html

```
 <div style="display:none" class="content"> </div>
```

javascript

```
  <script>   
 if(condition == true) { 
  x = document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: If you find this use full and your problem is solved then please accept my answer